# When using ArcGIS Georeferencing tool, why does fourth point show up as yellow crosshair?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, georeferencing

When using the Georeferencing tool of ArcGIS Desktop, why does the fourth point show up as a yellow crosshair?

I have never had this happen before and am worried that it may cause issues.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are selecting that point from the Link table [image], as you can see below:

[image]

If you remove selection, it will become red again:

[image]